# Sort elements alphabetically but keep one always at the beginning

Tags: c++, sorting

I have elements of the following type stored in a collection.

```cpp
class Element
{
public:
    bool IsDefault { false };
    std::wstring Name { };

    Element() = default;
    Element(const bool isDefault, std::wstring name) : IsDefault { isDefault }, Name { std::move(name) }
    {}

    bool operator==(const Element& other) const noexcept = default;
};
```

Note there can only be one element with `IsDefault == true`. What I want to achieve is sort the collection alphabetically (case-insensitive), but put the one element with `IsDefault == true` always at the beginning, regardless of its name.

My current code works, but I am looking for a way that is more efficient (as it is now, finding the one element with `IsDefault == true` takes `O(N)` and then sorting the collection takes [`O(N log N)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/sort) afterwards) ore more idiomatic / requires less code. What can I do to improve it? Is there a way to achieve my goal with a single call to `std::ranges::sort` or some other function?

I can make use of C++20 features if required.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector elements { Element(false, L"World"), Element(true, L"Foo"), Element(false, L"Zoo"), Element(false, L"Bar") };

    // Find the default element and remove it from the vector.
    Element defaultElement;

    for (const auto& e : elements)
    {
        if (e.IsDefault)
        {
            defaultElement = e;
            std::erase(elements, e);
            break;
        }
    }

    // Sort the remaining elements alphabetically
    std::ranges::sort(elements, [](const Element& a, const Element& b) noexcept
                      {
                          const auto& first { a.Name };
                          const auto& second { b.Name };
                          return ::_wcsnicmp(first.c_str(), second.c_str(), std::min(first.size(), second.size())) < 0;
                      });

    // Insert the default element at index 0
    elements.insert(std::begin(elements), defaultElement);

    _ASSERT(elements.at(0).Name == L"Foo");
    _ASSERT(elements.at(1).Name == L"Bar");
    _ASSERT(elements.at(2).Name == L"World");
    _ASSERT(elements.at(3).Name == L"Zoo");
}
```

Comment: Modify your comparison function to take `IsDefault` into account.

Comment: After you find the default element, can't you swap it with the first, and then sort the others? Alternatively, define a custom comparison to make the default smaller than anything else.

Comment: Aside: [the example code](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits#Example) for `std::char_traits` has case-insensitive comparison

Comment: Beware, your comparison function says that `"foo"` and `"foo1"` compare equal, as would `"foo"` and `"foo2"` but that `"foo1"` < `"foo2"`. Said differently is does not define a strict weak ordering relation.

Comment: @SergeBallesta thank you, I did not notice that. Using custom `char_traits` as recommended to me above would work, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the default in the comparison:

```
if(a.default != b.default)
    return b.default < a.default; // true, if a is true -> a is less
    // or more elegant (thanks, Adrian, for the hint): simply
    return a.default;

// rest of comparison
```

Comment: Thank you.  Operator `<` for `bool`s looks weird, but your comment explains it and it works and does the job both more efficiently and in fewer lines of code.

Comment: Maybe `if (a.IsDefault || b.IsDefault) return a.IsDefault;` is clearer and more concise?

Comment: I always like to delegate to `tuple::operator<`, so `std::tuple(!a.IsDefault, ci_view(a.Name)) < std::tuple(!b.IsDefault, ci_view(b.Name))`